# Como identificar fim de entradas em C++ usando o cin

Tags: c++

No trabalho da minha faculdade, nós submetemos o nosso código a uma plataforma que "corrige" o código automaticamente (insere as entradas no código e compara as saídas geradas com o gabarito).

Para pegarmos as entradas, sempre utilizamos o comando `cin`.

Para exemplificar meu problema: Suponha que eu tenha a seguinte entrada:

```
1 1 
2 3
5 8
0 0
```

E tenha que que dar como saída a soma de cada par de números, até que os dois sejam 0, o que identifica o fim das entradas.

O código seria algo do tipo:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

   int x,y;

   do{

       cin >> x;
       cin >> y;

       if(x != 0 && y != 0){

          z = x + y;
          cout << z << endl;

       }//fim if

   }while(x != 0 && y != 0);//fim do.while

   return 0;

}//fim main
```

Agora, preciso resolver o mesmo problema, entretanto, o final das entradas é demarcado pelo fim do arquivo (ao contrário de ter o par de entradas 0,0).

Qual a condição que tenho que colocar no lugar de `while(x != 0 && y != 0);` para que isso aconteça?

Comment: O comando em questão é `cin.eof()`

Answer (score 1):

Quando uma leitura não é possivel de ser feita o `cin` fica marcado como invalido, que quando avaliado como booleano vai dar falso. Isto permite-lhe fazer coisas como:

```
if (cin >> x){

}
```

Que apenas irá entrar no `if` se foi possível ler para a variável `x`. Extrapolando esta ideia para o seu programa pode alterar o seu `while` para:

```
while (cin >> x && cin >> y)
```

Que irá executar enquanto for possivel de ler tanto para `x` como `y`.

Código completo para referência:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   int x, y;

   while (cin >> x && cin >> y){
       int z = x + y;
       cout << z << endl;    
   }

   return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Tenho uma dúvida. C++ dá alguma garantia de que o primeiro `cin` será executado primeiro?

Comment: @HenriqueSchiessPertussati Sim porque a condição é interpretada da esquerda para a direita e com o operador lógico e(&&). Por esse motivo o primeiro é sempre o `cin>>x` e só se esse for lido com sucesso é lido o `cin>>y`.